# Can't parse jsonb Operator in JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jsonb

I'm trying to fetch the rows that have at least one matching element in the jsonb array field from an input list. jsobb_column of table_a is a jsonb field that stores values in the form of an array.

The following sql query works correctly:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a
where table_a.jsobb_column ?| array['item1', 'item2'];
```

The JPA query would look like this:

```
"select distinct table_a.* FROM table_a where table_a.jsonb_column ?| array[?0] "
```

Since JPA is not able to parse the syntax "?|" used for the jsonb operator, an error is thrown:

```
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mixing of ? parameters and other forms like ?0 is not supported!
```

I tried two different approaches to solve this problem:

1. Use "ESCAPE" to escape the "?" character, but it didn't work as expected.
2. Transfer one part of the query as a string parameter. The JPA query looks like follows:

```
"select distinct table_a.* FROM table_a where table_a.jsonb_column ?0 "
```

where the parameter at position 0 is a string variable with the following value:
"?| array['item1', 'item2']"

In this case I receive the following error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$0"
```

DB: postgresql

Questions:

1. How to escape the "?|" operator, so that the query will be executed?
2. Is there another way to build the query to accieve the same result?

Comment: This is not covered by the JPA specification; you might need to get the connection and prepare your statement yourself instead of use JPA to process your SQL string. Alternatively, JPA providers allow you to manipulate what it uses to delimit parameters (see https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/q_jdbc_parameter-delimiter.htm for an example in EclipseLink).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to fix the query in JPA. The solution was simply to use the function jsonb_exists_any().
The query would look like this:

```
"select distinct table_a.* FROM table_a where jsonb_exists_any(table_a.jsonb_column, array[?0]) = true "
```